# How to protect password in java- httpclient method

Tags: java, http, httpclient

How can i protect the password sending through HttpGet method.

```
HttpGet_getMethod = new HttpGet();
_getMethod = new HttpGet("url");
_getMethod.addHeader(USERNAME,PASSWORD);  // Here the password is sending without any protection mechanism and it is a security breach
```

if server is not accepting the encrypted password how can we send the password in a protected mode using httpclient.

Please share any link that shows password protection in httpclient method.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use ssl?

Comment: If the server doesn't accepted an encrypted password, then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @AlexSalauyou  could you please share the exact  link for SSL and httpclient combination ?, As i tried the same in google and confused with all.